# Audio File Not Getting Uploaded with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, audio

I tried The following code to upload files without pressing submit button. It works for images not for audio or video. When Audio File is uploaded it says undefined index 'file' in the log.

```js
<script>
$('#headerimage').on('change', function() {
var form = document.getElementById('fileupload');
            var fileInput = document.getElementById('headerimage');
            var file = fileInput.files[0];
            var formData = new FormData();
            var filename = '';
            formData.append('file', file);
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    filaname = xhr.responseText;
     console.log(xhr.responseText);
                }
            }
            // Add any event handlers here...
            xhr.open('POST', form.getAttribute('action'), true);
            xhr.send(formData);
   });
</script>
```

```html
<form id="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload2.php">
     <input type="file" id="headerimage" spellcheck="true" class="typography" name="headerimage">
</form>
```

```html
<?php
if(!empty($_FILES)) 
{
    $file = $_FILES;
    if($file['file']['error'] == 0) 
    {
        $name = explode('.', $file['file']['name']);
        $newName = $name[count($name)-1];
        if (move_uploaded_file($file['file']['tmp_name'], "uploads/".$newName)) 
        {
            echo $newName;
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        echo "err";
        exit;
    }
} else {
    echo "errrror";
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Which log? PHP log or browser log? Also, add full error stack please.